# Rails 3 gives routing error with point in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a search form written with Rails 3 when I query it everything works fine as long as I do not put a point in my query. Eg:

```
http://localhost:3000/en/job/search/q/test     - WORKS
http://localhost:3000/en/job/search/q/test.    - DOES NOT WORK
```

URL with point at the end gives a

```
Routing Error: No route matches [GET] "/en/job/search/q/test.
```

Does anybody know how I can solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Rails is expecting a `:format` (e.g. js) after the dot by default. If you want to override please provide your `routes.rb`.

Comment: My routes.rb file for this particular route is:  

`R326::Application.routes.draw do  
  scope '(:locale)' do  
    match 'job/search/(:param1/:value1(/:param2/:value2/(:param3/:value3/(:param4/:value4/(:param5/:value5/(:param6/:value6/(:param7/:value7/(:param8/:value8/(:param9/:value9/(:param10/:value10/(:param11/:value11/(:param12/:value12))))))))))))' => 'job#search'  

    root :to => 'job#index'  
  end  
end  
`
What should I change to override this behaviour. Using POST requests is not really an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Rails interprets everything to the right of the decimal as the format. You need to set the :constraints

Here is a good article on the subject: http://coding-journal.com/rails-3-routing-parameters-with-dots/

Here is the reference in the Rails API that should help you resolve your issue:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-constraints

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments

Since your passing a string in the search as a get request, you might also consider route globbing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing

Your route would be something like this:

```
match ":language/job/search/*query"
```

and in your controller, you would get the value from the route using the params[] array:

```
q = params[:query]
```

Be sure to use best practices when passing this to ActiveRecord to avoid a SQL injection attack.

Comment: I managed to get it sorted out by following the info in the article http://coding-journal.com/rails-3-routing-parameters-with-dots/

Answer (score 0):

What @iltempo said.

Also, it would be a good idea to switch your search from using GET requests to POST requests to make all these problems go away.